# How to override sendkeys() method using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to override `sendkeys()`. It should clear first then enter the key

```
public Actions SendKeys(string keysToSend){

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? call `element.clear()`

Comment: I am handling a old  project , where they have used only sendkeys() without clearing the existing content in all the places. so i want to use some thing like override of method. so that i can save my effort

Comment: You mean they used `webelement.sendKeys()` everywhere? or they used some general method like the one you posted?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation the [`sendKeys()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/server/handler/SendKeys.html) method is defined as:

```
void sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keysToSend)

Parameters:
keysToSend - character sequence to send to the element
Throws:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - if keysToSend is null
```

So, its clear that we can't override `SendKeys()` method in the first place.

### Alternative

As an alternative, referring to the discussion [A general question about Java and WebDriver](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/E0tBfsoJGPQ) @KrishnanMahadevan mentions that you can make an attempt to override **`sendKeys()`** method following the below mentioned concepts, steps and procedure:

- The concept may vary depending on what *WebDriver* variant you are working with.
- As all of the *WebDriver* implementations extend *RemoteWebDriver* and you are only going to work with *RemoteWebDriver*, so while working with *Selenium Grid* you can use the following tweak.
- If you are not working with *RemoteWebDriver* but instead working with **GeckoDriver**, **ChromeDriver**, **IEDriverServer**, then you would need to `extend` the respective classes, `override` all of the `findElement()`, `findElements()`, etc methods in these classes to return an instance of **my_web_element**.
- **my_web_element** would basically be your class wherein you would extend **RemoteWebElement** and then override
  [**`org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(CharSequence...)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

The above step will definitely get you started.